# Binding JSON URL to IMG in Vue 3

Tags: json, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm building an app in Vue 3 that lists local stores. To add and remove stores I've made a JSON file that lists them, including a URL to an image icon (SVG). The JSON file is imported in my Vue component and lists the stores correctly. However, this is not the case for the image files, see code below.

**JSON**

```
[
  {
    "storeName": "Kapper",
    "storeId": "s0001",
    "imgUrl": ""
  },
  {
    "storeName": "Manicure",
    "storeId": "s0002",
    "imgUrl": ""
  },
  {
    "storeName": "Supermarkt",
    "storeId": "s0003",
    "imgUrl": "../../assets/icons/021-grocery.svg"
]
```

**VUE**

```
<template>
    <ul class="storeList">
        <li class="store" v-for="data in $options.stores" v-bind:key="data">
            {{data.storeName}}
            <img :src="data.imgUrl"/>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
    import stores from './stores.json'
    export default {
        stores: stores,
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
    @import './styles.scss';
</style>
```

Some things I found out:

- Hardcoding the URL seems to work fine
- Placeholders from the web also seems to work fine (e.g https://picsum.photos/200 works perfectly)
- Other file extensions such as .png also don't work

Answer (score 0):

Changing the directory of the icons is what worked for me in the end. Changed the icons from the "assets" folder to the "public" folder.